# How to access a variable in parent controller without $scope?

Tags: angularjs, scope, controller

I am writing an app with angularjs and I don't know how to access the variables in my main-controller.

```
gsg_main.controller('mainCtrl',['$scope','SessionService','$http','$routeParams','MessageService','$interval','$location','orderByFilter',function($scope,SessionService,$http,$routeParams,MessageService,$interval,$location,orderBy){
//variablen
var self = this;
self.username = "any_name";
```

I want to access username from a nested controller:

```
gsg_main.controller('testCtrl',['$scope',function($scope){
var self = this;
self.testvar = $scope.$parent.username;
```

}]);

I also tried:

```
self.testvar = $scope.$parent.parent.username;
```

which I found in other posts.

Is there a way without using $scope in the main-controller?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You could always use a service to share values between controllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a service:

```
  .service('UsernameService', function() {
    var username = null;

    this.setUsername = function(value) {
      username = value;
    };

    this.getUsername = function() {
      return username;
    }
  })
```

Inject it into your controllers:

```
  .controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', 'UsernameService', function($scope, UsernameService) { ... }
```

Then you can call these functions to get and set the username value:

```
 UsernameService.setUsername("any_name");
 ...
 self.testvar = UsernameService.getUsername();
```